# Adding custom items to stackpanel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I'm working on a project (for Windows Phone 8 with Visual Studio 2012 with C#) where I want to display some items that each have:

1. a picture
2. a title
3. a description
4. to be able to be clicked (so that I can navigate to a certain Page)

So I thought I could do that with a stackpanel. But I'm not sure how I can add items that have the above properties and to be able to add those items from XAML. I tired adding items through a ItemsControl in stackpanel but I'm not sure how I can add more complex items like the one I want.

Comment: you need [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol) with custom [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) where you can specify layout for your picture, title, ....

Comment: Ok let me try see If I can find something about this :)

Comment: You just add your class (view model) to items, or bound collection, and view for it is created from `DataTemplate`

Comment: I don't have any class with items. I just want to manually add items in my Itemscontrol and be able to change picture and text from XAML

Comment: I started doing something else. Not sure if it's the right one or if there is any better way but I think it could work. I made an ItemsControl and made a grid with all the above properties I wanted. And then I'll just copy paste the grid in the ItemsControl as many times as the number of the items I want and then I'll change each idividuaal property fromeach grid from XAML.

Comment: I think you mean you want to make a usercontrol ?

Comment: If I understand from some tutorials I just watched, it looks like I may want something like usercontrol yes. If my current method doesn't work, I'll try usercontrol ty ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use a ListBox or LongListSelector rather than a StackPanel. You can then:

- Data bind the list to the control itself, which will handle adding/deleting items from the control automatically
- Define the view for each control using ListBox's ItemTemplate property

First of all, in your code-behind/ViewModel/what-have-you, you'll want to create an ObservableCollection of objects to display. ObservableCollection will let the control know to update in the case an item is added, removed, etc.

```
public ObservableCollection<T> foo = new ObservableCollection<T>();
```

In XAML, you'll then want to databind this ObservableCollection to the ListBox you've created:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding foo}" />
```

Finally, you can define the ItemTemplate of the ListBox like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding foo}" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'd highly recommend reading [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), especially "Binding a control to a collection of objects" and the section after on DataTemplates. :)

Comment: Ty very much ;) Although I used itemscontrol instead of listbox or longlistselector, but I'll try those too. ;)